# Calculating unbalanced binary trees

Tags: algorithms, binary-trees

Two-part question:

1. Is there any more specific name than "unbalanced binary tree" to describe the tree below? The distinguishing characteristics are:

   i. The root node and left children must have either 0 or 2 children.

   ii. Right children must have 0 children.

   iii. All nodes must be positive non-zero integers.

   iv. Any node with children must equal the sum of its children.
2. Given the value of the root node (in this case, 77), is there a standard algorithm to efficiently calculate all possible trees of this type?

   - i.e. `(77, 76, 1)`, ..., `(77, 1, 76)`, `(77, (76, 75, 1), 1)`, etc.

---

```
         77
        /  \
       68   9
      /  \
     48   20
    /   \
   47    1
  /  \
 42   5
```

Comment: I think this tree is similar to something sometimes known as a caterpillar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algorithm to enumerate all possible trees meeting your conditions. These trees are in bijection with their sequence of leaves. Given a root value $n$, iterate sequence lengths from 1 to $n$. For a length $l$ you wish to enumerate all sequences of positive numbers of length $l$ adding to $n$. If $l=1$ choose the sequence consisting of $n$. If $l>1$ enumerate possibilities 1 to $n-l+1$ for the first number $a$ and generate remaining numbers as a sequence of length $l-1$ adding to $n-a$.

In Haskell this could be implemented as:

```
seqsTo n = concatMap (seqsToOfLength n) [1..n]
seqsToOfLength n 1 = [[n]]
seqsToOfLength n l = concatMap (\a -> map (a:) (seqsToOfLength (n-a) (l-1))) [1..n-l+1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just tested this out and it looks like it works as expected. Here's a live JS version for anyone else who needs to try it out: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkvfaa

Answer (score 1):

It is a special caterpillar. 
Let $d(i)$ be the number of such trees with root $i$. We have $d(1)=1$; and $d(n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}d(i)+1$, where "plus 1" is for the case of no children and $d(i)$ in sigma for the case that the left child is $i$. 
One can easily compute $d(n)$ in $O(n)$ time using a simple loop. Or it is not hard to solve the recurrence relation and get $d(i)=2^{i-1}$ for $i\geq 1$.